# Avoid multiple autocomplete calls by wrapping it with SetTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, settimeout

Here's my issue : using an autocomplete jQuery plugin, I'd like to avoid multiple ajax requests when user strikes his keynoard by surrounding the

```
$('#query1').autocomplete({
                    serviceUrl:'/actions/autocomplete?population=salon',
                    minChars:3, 
                    maxHeight:300,
                    width:200,
                    clearCache:true,
                    onSelect: function(suggestions,data){ $(".btn1").attr("href", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/actions/espaceClients?participantId=" + data) }
                });
```

with something like

```
                var search = false;
            $('#query1, #query2, #query3').keyup(function(){
                if (!search){
                    search = true;
                }
                if (search) {
                    search = false;
                    autocompleteThem();
                }
            });
```

A you can see, above code is stupid, but it kinda shows what i'm trying to do.

In simple words, if user dosen't type anything else in a certain period of time, then you can call autocomplete.

I hope i'm being clear, as my brains are a mess...

Comment: i am after similar what you doing, would you please share the sample code? are you using asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`deferRequestBy` option](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#howto) on that plugin, like this:

```
$('#query1').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl:'/actions/autocomplete?population=salon',
                minChars:3, 
                maxHeight:300,
                width:200,
                clearCache:true,
                deferRequestBy: 200, //200ms
                onSelect: function(suggestions,data){ $(".btn1").attr("href", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/actions/espaceClients?participantId=" + data) }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to prevent multiple simultanious requests? This will inhibit the usefulness of this plugin. You can either add a delay to the request, or use a plugin such as [AjaxQueue](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) to ensure the results come back to the browser in the right order.

To use the built-in [delay](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#options) parameter (from the manual):

> The delay in milliseconds the
>   Autocomplete waits after a keystroke
>   to activate itself. A zero-delay makes
>   sense for local data (more
>   responsive), but can produce a lot of
>   load for remote data, while being less
>   responsive.

Initialize a autocomplete with the delay option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 0 });
```

Get or set the delay option, after init.

```
//getter
var delay = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "delay" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "delay", 0 );
```

The equivalent of the delay parameter for the [autocomplete plugin you're using](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) is

```
deferRequestBy
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using an external plugin  : http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/